# MySQL appropriate way to select data using CASE .. WHEN syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small table named `sample_table`:

```
    Column               Data Type
     id                  int PK NOT NULL
     d1                  date NOT NULL
     d2                  date NOT NULL
```

I want to select the interval between `d1` and `d2` in years, based on the condition that if the difference is not an integer number, then the `ceiling` of the difference will be selected, else the `floor` of the difference will be selected.

I have tried doing this using `CASE ... WHEN`:

```
SELECT( 
CASE 
    WHEN (((DATEDIFF(d1,d2)/365)%1) != 0) THEN CEILING(DATEDIFF(d1,d2)/365) 
    ELSE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(d1,d2)/365) 
END CASE)
AS diff
FROM sample_table
```

but getting the following error:

```
 Error Code: 1064
 Syntax error near 'case when (((DATEDIFF(d1,d2)/365))!=0) THEN CEILING (DATEDIFF(d' on line 2
```

My sample input:

```
   id            d1                d2
    1        2013-10-25        2014-10-22
    2        2012-10-25        2014-10-25
    3        2014-10-28        2014-10-28
    4        2012-10-23        2014-10-26
```

My expected output:

```
   diff
    1
    2
    0
    3
```

I know something is wrong with my `CASE ... WHEN` syntax, only I just can't figure out where, and how to do it correctly.

Comment: I think the second CASE  after END is the culprit.

Comment: +1 You're right. It should end with only `END` and not `END CASE`. I actually got confused about the `CASE ... END` syntax. Thanks a lot. Problem solved.

Comment: What's the significance of 365?

Comment: @Strawberry DATEDIFF(d1,d2) returns a value that indicates the number of days between d1 and d2. I want to get the number of years in the range of d1 and d2. 1 year = 365 days, hence division by 365 in order to get the number of years. Simple as that.

Comment: However, there is one case I forgot about. The case of **LEAP YEARS**. On leap years, the number of total days is not 365 days, rather 366 days.

Comment: That's rather my point. And what is the floor of an integer number?

Comment: You got me. I really didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing second CASE after END

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN (((DATEDIFF(d1,d2)/365)%1) != 0) THEN CEILING(DATEDIFF(d1,d2)/365) 
ELSE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(d1,d2)/365) 
END AS diff
FROM sample_table
```

Comment: Although keeping parenthesis doesn't affect getting the correct output, I'm marking this solution as answer, as it seems a better and neater approach. Thanks again buddy!

Comment: Thank you .I ll edit the answer to correspond to the initial problem.

Comment: Note that when d2 is greater then d1 it should be first in the expression. Also `CEIL(DATEDIFF('2014-10-27', '2014-10-26')/365)` will result in 1

Answer (score 2):

@geoandri gave the correct answer on the proper use of `case`, but note you don't really need it. For integer numbers, `x = floor(x) = ceiling(x)`. So you might as well just always call `ceiling`, and be done with it:

```
SELECT CEILING((DATEDIFF(d1,d2)/365))
FROM   sample_table
```

Comment: @Muereinik You're absolutely right!!!! This is really awesome, why didn't I think of this before? No need to do the hastle with all those CASE... WHEN stuff, this query is much shorter, much easier and gives me the exact same answer. Sorry bud, I can't really mark this as an answer now, but clearly, this is the most appropriate approach. Thank you very much. Excellent answer. +1. :)

Comment: See comment at geoandri's answer